AWS Lambda monitor dependencies
I have an AWS Lambda python application, lets call it A. It calls multiple services, lets call one of them B. I would like to know how can I monitor in CloudWatch connection between A and B, namely:

What is a latency of A calling B
What is an invocation count of A calling B
What is an error rate of A calling B?

Edit:
B can be:

Another lambda on the same account
Another AWS service (S3, Verified Permissions in this case) - this is already covered
Another service running on AWS, but on differenct account and connected though internet


AWS X-Ray might be able to help, if service B is another AWS service. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/aws-xray.html Your question is a bit too vague to provide a more concrete answer.

I have added clarification

you can use cloudwatch custom metrics, integrate x-ray to trace your lambd

If you decide to go the CloudWatch custom metrics route, consider using Powertools for AWS Lambda.

AWS X-Ray would help to monitor the calls and detailed information about the invoke time, execution time and other important details.
